# How to add line breaks to (hyperref) pdf form TextField after 2020?

Tags: hyperref, textfield

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416218/how-to-add-line-breaks-to-hyperref-pdf-form-textfield). The given answer from Ulrike Fischer is not working for the hyperref package after 2020 any more.

### Steps to reproduce:

- open [TeXLive online](https://texlive.net/run)
- insert

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{Form}
    \TextField[multiline,width=\textwidth,
    value={%
      You should write your feedback in a readable way, for example using bullet points:\string\n
      * Insert at least 1 positive comment (mandatory)\string\n
      * Insert at least 1 critical comment or question (mandatory)\string\n
      Use multiple paragraphs.
      \string\n
      Some examples of concrete, actionable feedback:\string\n
      * The first figure does not have a caption; please add it.\string\n
      * The derivation of Equation (7) became unclear around Equation (5). I think this is because you did not make the substitution of x explicit and feel doing so would make the argument clearer.\string\n%
  },
  name=mytextfield]{}%
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

### Result:

There are Chinese symbols instead of newline characters.
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

you can use \textCR or \textLF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
  \centering
  \begin{Form}
    \TextField[multiline,width=\textwidth,
    value={%
      You\textLF blub
  },
  name=mytextfield]{}%
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```